# Command/scripts to check the Reverse DNS Lookup time

Tags: linux, networking, shell-script, dns

I am working on a project in which one master communicates with numbers of slaves. For that it has to make connection with hosts in network. But sometimes it hangs.

I think that the reason behind is extra time consumption during **Reverse DNS Lookup**.
So please tell me any command or script which checks or makes the list for the **Reverse DNS Lookup** time.

**EDIT no. 1**

Tell also that where can I add that command in rsh source code so that I got a list of time consumed by every request, whenever it connects to other hosts.

So that I can find the reason behind the hanging of server.

Comment: Yes it does a reverse dns lookup.

Comment: Can you tell where can I add this command in rsh source code, so that I can check, Reverse DNS lookup time, or, if I am wrong then correct me. Please.

Comment: question edited...

Comment: Actually my task is the same that I Edited. But my question is the approach that I thought.

Answer (score 2):

Some of this depends on which stub resolver is in use. You may also be having problems with IPv6, e.g. if IPv6 AAAA records are returned but there is no IPv6 connectivity.

Assuming the software (erm, `rsh`? really? this answer isn't `rsh` specific) is using the system resolver (like `ping`), and not its own implementation (like `dig` or `host`), then you can use `getent` to see what might be happening:

```
$ time getent ahostsv4 www.google.com
$ time getent ahostsv6 www.google.com
```

The above will perform a forward and reverse lookup (though you cannot force `getent` to look up a reverse PTR or other types, it only cares about A/AAAA records).

There are a couple of handy scripts in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/7088/152887) to https://serverfault.com/questions/7056/whats-the-reverse-dns-command-line-utility , these allow you to do forward a reverse lookups (IPv4 only) like `getent hosts`, but in perl so you can tinker with them.

The above two possibilities use your system resolver, including all the swings and roundabouts involved in nsswitch, so they *should* behave the way most applications do.

Don't forget to test on the client *and* the server, either or both will do reverse look ups.

You can also check your local resolvers one by one:

```
$ while read opt p1 ;  do 
    [ "$opt" = "nameserver" ] && dig @$p1 www.google.com +short +identify; 
done < /etc/resolv.conf
```

and to check reverse DNS:

```
$ dig www.google.com +short | xargs -n1 -i dig -x {} PTR +short +identify
```

To further debug this, you will need to check:

- [`/etc/host.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/host.conf.5.html)  (various options, including spoof checking via reverse DNS)
- [`/etc/resolv.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html) (your resolvers)
- [`/etc/nsswitch.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html) (what databases to check, e.g. `/etc/hosts`, DNS, LDAP, etc)
- the output of [`dnstrace`](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/debugging.html) and/or `dig +trace`
- [`/etc/gai.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/gai.conf.5.html), if present. Amongst other things, this can control whether IPV6 AAAA records are sorted before A records.
- [`/etc/nscd.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nscd.conf.5.html) if `nscd` is in use

If you have wireshark and root access, you can watch DNS requests on the wire:

```
# tshark -w dns.cap "port 53"
# tshark -V -ta -n -r dns.cap
```

(The `-V` option is overly verbose, however it hasn't occurred to the developers to put  timestamps in the protocol dissection output with `-O dns`. Maybe that's fixed in a newer version.)

Even if you're not using `nscd` right now, you can easily see *some* of what's happening if you start it interactively with the option `-dd` or `-ddd`. Note that `nscd` only caches host (A/AAAA) records, so PTR records will end up negatively cached with a short (default 20s) lifetime.

The glibc resolver (and others) supports "`options debug`" in `/etc/resolv.conf` as well as the environment variable `RES_OPTIONS` which can be used to enable debug. Sadly, this useful functionality requires that DEBUG is enabled when glibc is built, so it's rather unlikely you'll be able to use it...

For heavy lifting, the best candidate is [`ltrace`](http://www.ltrace.org/), this lets you trace and timestamp library calls, just like the way `strace` can trace system calls, e.g. `gethostbyname()` or `gethostbyaddr()`. The downside: with the many layers of indirection offered by [*nsswitch*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch), you'll probably get lost in the voluminous output. A simple run on telnet got me 3000+ lines of output, within which is buried two calls to `gethostbyname()`.

```
$ ltrace -ttT -e "getaddr*+gethost*+getname*" getent ahosts www.google.com

13:42:06.118718 getent->getaddrinfo("www.google.com", nil, { 0x2a, 0, 0, 0, 0, nil, 
nil, nil }, { 0x2a, 0x2, 0x3, 0, 16, { 2, 0, { 0x69187d4a } }, "www.google.com", { 
0x2a, 0x2, 0x2, 0x11, 16, { 2, 0, { 0x93187d4a } }, nil, { 0x2a, 0x2, 0x3, 0, 16, {
2, 0, { 0x67187d4a } }, nil, { 0x2a, 0x2, 0x2, 0x11, 16, { 2, 0, { 0x68187d4a } }, 
nil, ... } } } }) = 0 <0.042561>
```

It's a little harder to understand what's going on because it doesn't output human readable IP addresses (`0x69187d4a` = 105,24,125,74 -> 74.125.24.105). It is probably the best method to track down local problems though, as you can see all the calls through NSS.

I used these amendments in my `~/.ltrace.conf` for the above, it may require some further hacking:

```
typedef size_t = int;
typedef sockaddr = struct(short, short, in_addr);
typedef addrinfo = struct;
typedef addrinfo = struct(hex(int), hex(int), hex(int), hex(int), size_t, sockaddr*, string, addrinfo *);

int getaddrinfo(string, string, addrinfo *, +addrinfo**);
int getnameinfo(sockaddr*, uint, +string, +uint, +string, +uint, uint);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have doubts in Slow response in reverse query then you can try either of the methods below to rectify the same:

1. If possible then disable reverse lookup in your application and see the difference
2. You can use Name Service Cache Daemon (nscd) which also caches PTR but there is some security issue as :

   > The Name Service Cache Daemon  (nscd)  has a default behavior  that
   >   does not allow applications to  validate DNS "PTR" records  against
   >   "A" records.
   >
   > In particular, nscd caches a request for a "PTR" record, and when a
   >   request  comes later for the "A"  record,  nscd simply divulges the
   >   information from  the cached "PTR"  record, instead of querying the
   >   authoritative DNS for the "A" record.

Reference [Link](http://forum.valhallalegends.com/index.php?topic=5170.0)

Comment: These are the lines from given links `Important!  If you are running a service that relies on forward/reverse lookup checks, don't do this!`.

Comment: But firstly I want to make a table of time consumed in Reverse DNS Lookup. Tell me how can I do this first. I want to analyse the delay first. Solve my problem. If this is the reason then I can apply your methods.

Comment: The `nscd`/PTR issue is a [very old bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56545), fixed very a long time ago...