# Method to perform DNS lookup step very quickly during wget

Tags: bash, logs, dns, wget

When I download any document from internet using **wget**. It shows maximum amount of time consumed in **getaddrinfo()**.

I know **getaddrinfo()** used for DNS lookup.

Tell me any method, so that this time is reduced to negligible, just like making any table for host name and their corresponding IP address, so that wget can get coresponding IP address very quickly.

**Question**

Tell me also, how can I implement this. Thanks in advance. Looking for your kind response.

**Command, I use**

```
ltrace -c -o log_ltrace_wget_new1.txt wget http://www.ada.gov/briefs/kovacsbr.doc
```

**Output**

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls      function
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------------------
 67.11    7.070607      336695        21    select
 19.67    2.071956        5739       361    strlen
 10.59    1.115199     1115199         1    getaddrinfo
  0.32    0.033705         298       113    fgets
  0.27    0.028261         197       143    malloc
  .....
  .....
  .....
```

Comment: Possibly it's trying to do a AAAA query to resolve IPv6 addresses and that timesout or something along those lines. Try a network capture to get a better idea of what's causing the delay.

Answer (score 3):

Build a local dns cache using `nscd` (Name service cache daemon) or dnsmasq (A real dns server)

Otherwise alternate your default dns server from `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: I added IP address of `www.ada.gov`, i.e., `149.101.146.61` in resolv.conf. [In vi editor, it shows this line in red background] .But it shows the same time consumed in getaddrinfo.

Comment: @jhamb then there's no way to improve it unless you give up glibc

Comment: But there is no change shown in time consumed in `getaddrinfo()`. If I resolve DNS locally, then it should show less time than previous. Why it does not show less time ?

Comment: Note that at least on Debian and Ubuntu, host caching is disabled in the default configuration, so you need to reenable it.

Comment: How can I do this ?? Please explain.

Comment: @jhamb, edit /etc/nscd.conf, change no to yes for host caching and restart nscd (`service nscd restart`)

Comment: @jhamb jftr if you added `www.ada.gov` to `resolv.conf` nothing will change as it is the wrong configuration file. Either try to use another dns server like `8.8.8` or add `www.ada.gov` to `/etc/hosts` or follow stephanes advice

Comment: ohk. Wait, I am trying the same.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I replace `enable-cache <service> <yes|no>` to `enable-cache service yes`, as user account is of name `service`. Is it sufficient to overcome from getaddrinfo time consumed ?

Comment: @UlrichDangel Tell me one more thing, if I want to do reverse DNS Lookup vry quickly like this, [ i.e., `getnameinfo`], as this is important step in mirroring . How can I do this ?

Some of my questions link are as follows, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66700/how-to-detect-particular-system-call-called-or-not-in-a-whole-workflow

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65745/command-scripts-to-check-the-reverse-dns-lookup-time

This will help you to understand my task. Please help me.

Comment: @UlrichDangel Actually in mirroring, rsync and rsh is used, and Reverse DNS Lookup is required whenever master starts copying data in mirrors for authenticating the IP address.

Comment: @UlrichDangel If you are free, or just have 10 minutes, can we discuss on chat. Please.